# How do I pass pyspark dataframe to custom map function as an argument (multiple map arguments)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

sal_df = spark.createDataFrame([100,200,300], "integer").toDF("salary")
sal_rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([1000,2000,3000])

def processDataLine(arg1, arg2, df):
    def _processDataLine(row):
        return df.count() + arg1 + arg2 + row
    return _processDataLine


arg1, arg2 = 0, 0
sal_rdd.map(processDataLine(arg1, arg2, sal_df))
```

ERROR -

```
Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o5792.__getstate__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getstate__([]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

**PicklingError**: Could not serialize object: Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o5792.__getstate__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getstate__([]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I think we can not directly pass pyspark dataframe to custom map function.
I need to access sal_df inside _processDataLine function to do further processing.

I have tried passing

```
def processDataLine(arg1, arg2, df_json):
    def _processDataLine(dataline):
        return len(df_json) + arg1 + arg2 + dataline
    return _processDataLine

sal_rdd.map(processDataLine(arg1, arg2, sal_df.toJSON())).take(10)
```

**ERROR -**

```
PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Exception: It appears that you are attempting to broadcast an RDD or reference an RDD from an action or transformation. RDD transformations and actions can only be invoked by the driver, not inside of other transformations; for example, rdd1.map(lambda x: rdd2.values.count() * x) is invalid because the values transformation and count action cannot be performed inside of the rdd1.map transformation. For more information, see SPARK-5063.
```

Also working,

```
def processDataLine(arg1, arg2, df_list):
    def _processDataLine(dataline):
        return len(df_list) + arg1 + arg2 + dataline
    return _processDataLine

sal_rdd.map(processDataLine(arg1, arg2, sal_df.toJSON().collect())).take(10)

OUTPUT - [1003, 2003, 3003]
```

How do I directly pass and access pyspark dataframe object inside _processDataLine.

Comment: What is your goal? I didn't get it why do you need the map of rdd. Simply you can use the dataframe functions.

Comment: I am using map of rdd here just for looping. My main goal is to access dataframe obj inside processDataLine. At the end after some processing _processDataLine will return some value

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([100,200,300], 'integer').toDF('salary')
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([1000,2000,3000], 'integer').toDF('value')

count = df1.count()
arg1 = 0
arg2 = 0

def func(count, arg1, arg2, df):
    return df2.withColumn('result', col('value') + lit(arg1) + lit(arg2) + lit(count))

df3 = func(count, arg1, arg2, df2)
df3.show()

+-----+------+
|value|result|
+-----+------+
| 1000|  1003|
| 2000|  2003|
| 3000|  3003|
+-----+------+
```